# Finding sampling size to disprove null-hypothesis

Tags: statistics

Suppse that the real value of $\lambda_R$ is $9$, the null hypothesis is given by $H_0$: $\lambda_R = 10$, the test-observator is $\hat\lambda_R$ with a normal distribution and that the standard deviation is given by $\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{n}}$. Find how large the sample size $n$ must be in order to disprove the null hypothesis with a test with a level of significance $\alpha = 0.05$ and a probability of $0.9$ to prove that $\lambda <10$ (disproving the null hypothesis).

In other words, i need to find and $n$ such that $P($disprove $H_0 | \lambda_R = 9) = 0.9$. In the task just prior to this one, I was asked to figure out wheter or not I could disprove the null hypothesis when $$\hat\lambda_R = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n X_i = \frac{470}{50} = 9.4,$$
where I found the $z$-value to be $-1.341$. Since this value is greater than $z_\alpha = -1.645$, where $\alpha = 0.05$ is the level of significance, the null hypothesis can not be disproven. I'm not sure if this result is needed to solve this task I'm working on. I've tried different approaches, but I never get the right value for $n$. The value for $n$ I'm supposed to get is $82$. I think this question is about the Type 2 error, but all of my attempts have proven wrong. Does someone know how I am supposed to solve this problem correctly?